# Spring webflux security - ConcurrentAuthentication Strategy

Tags: spring-security, spring-webflux

I am using Spring boot 2.5.6 with webflux security and would like to enforce only one session per user.

To implement this with non reactive security,

```
@Bean
    public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy = new ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy(sessionRegistry());
        sessionAuthenticationStrategy.setMaximumSessions(1);
        sessionAuthenticationStrategy.setExceptionIfMaximumExceeded(false);
        return sessionAuthenticationStrategy;
    }
```

I am not able to find the reactive security equivalent.

Comment: This feature is built on top of the Servlet API. Reactive support in spring-* projects uses Spring WebFlux, which is built on Project Reactor. Spring WebFlux does not have an equivalent (afaik) to `HttpSessionListener`, so there is no direct equivalent. If you have ideas for that, we'd love a feature suggestion with that info.